# Concerning Assonance

Tags: pronunciation, rhymes

Assonance, also known as "slant rhyme," is a repetition of vowel sounds that creates an illusion of rhyming. Wikipedia notes that it's "used in (mainly modern) English poetry."

Which leads me to believe that from Shakespeare's times and up to, say, the end of the 19th Century, the concept was frowned on by purists. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think that Keats or Byron ever used it.

I realize that in different regions of the English-speaking world different things are pronounced differently. That said, my ear (accustomed to the way certain vowels and consonants are pronounced along the Eastern Seaboard) tells me that "defiance" and "lions" do not rhyme.

If, for instance, you wrote a twenty-page-long poem; and if one of the poem's purposes was to imitate, or stylize, early 19th Century poetry; and if that poem consisted entirely of iambic lines; and if all those lines rhymed; and if all those rhymes were perfect or near-perfect - "defiance" and "lions" would stick out like an infected thumb.

Am I wrong?

Comment: [Assonance](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/learning/glossary-term/assonance) does not mean the same thing as [slant rhyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_rhyme).

Comment: To expand my previous comment (which I realize is too terse), *assonance* is generally applied to repeating vowel sounds internal to a line of poetry, and *slant rhyme* to words at the end of lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are incorrect about assonance (at least as I understand your assumptions.) That makes answering your question a bit tricky, because your presuppositions are wrong to begin with. And, no matter where you're from, *odds are* you'd pronounce then similarly.

About your assertions.

Assonance takes place when two or more words close to one another repeat the same vowel sound but start with different consonant sounds.

Assonance is common in *Sailing to Byzantium* by W. B. Yeats, (1865-1939)

> That is *no* country *for* *old* men. The *young*
>   In *one* *another*’s arms, birds in the trees...

Or *She Walks in Beauty* by George Gordon, Lord Byron (1788-1824)

> She walks in beauty, *like* the *night*
>           Of cloudless *climes* and st*ar*ry *skies*;
>       And all th*a*t's *best* of d*ar*k and *bright*
>           Meet in her *a*sp*ect* and her *eyes*:
>       Thus *mel*lowed to that *ten*der *light*
>           Which *hea*ven to gaudy day *denies*.

The stanza rime is ababab, but assonates as aaaaaa. This kind of double-effect was highly prized by Keats, Shelley and Byron, and others. And I'd call Yeats a purist. Interesting is the assonance placement of "starry skies" and "dark and bright", and "that's best" and "aspect". There's enough assonance here to float a boat.

Shakespeare's famous *Sonnet 55* also used assonance:

> N*ot* marble, nor the *gil*ded *mon*uments
>   Of *prin*ces, shall out*live* *this* p*ow*erful *rhyme*;
>   But you shall *shine* more *bright* in these c*on*tents
>   Than *un*swept stone, besmear'd with *slut*tish *time*.
>   When wasteful war shall statues o*ver*turn,
>   And broils root out the w*or*k of masonry,
>   *Nor* Mars his *sword nor war's* quick fire shall burn
>   The living re*cord* of y*our* *memory*.  ...

Never underestimate great poets.